# Zoom HyperV screen

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v, dpi

I was using HyperV for some time and everything was fine until my 1080p display just broke. I bought a new one which is 4k and encountered a problem: on my host system I set 175% zoom, but on HyperV machine it's not possible because of `cannot change this parameter on remote system`. So this is a problem: all fonts on VM are 2-3px of height and is just unusable.

Is it possible to change virtual DPI on VM screen to make fonts and icons larger like it is on my host machine?